# Javascript: Is it possible to inject new functions into a base 'class/object' that will be available in all sub-'classes/objects'?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I am trying to add a new property to a class in an existing JavaScript framework (Wireit).

The base class is called Container and I want all Containers to have a GUID property. Container is currently sub-classed to ImageContainer, FormContainer etc.

If I extend Container to have a GUID, would the GUID be available in ImageContainer, FormContainer etc.?

How would I do this? Examples?

Comment: Why not just add a property to each object after it's instantiated - `myContainer.guid = generateGuid()` ?

Comment: Hey, stop using my name!

Comment: @Paul - stop using *my* name! I was here first :-P

Comment: @Matt - The instantiation is done within the framework. Also the Save and Load functionality. So I guess I don't get a look in...

Comment: @paul, oh, right.  Well don't do anything to sully our name :)

Comment: @Matt because it's a bad practice (if you want to maintain the oop principles)

Comment: @gion_13 The best practice is to modify the constructor - but that would mean hacking the framework. Adding `guid` to the prototype is pointless because each object would have the same 'guid', which kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Javascript does not have classes.

Answer (score 3):

The way prototypical OO works is that when you :

- Look up a property on an object, say `imageContainer`
- It will look for properties on that object,
- If it can't find any it will look on the prototype (`ImageContainer.prototype`)
- If it can't find any it will look on the next prototype ('Container.prototype')
- And the next prototype ('Object.prototype') until the prototype chain is empty in which case it returns `undefined`.

This means if you add a property `GUID`

`Container.prototype.GUID = 42;`

All objects with `Container.prototype` in the prototype chain will *share* that property.

If you do not want that property to be shared then it's very difficult to add a unique GUID to all objects with `Container.prototype` in their prototype chain.

You can however use [`.isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) to check whether an object has a prototype in their chain.

**Example:**

```
var objs = [..]; // all objects 

objs.forEach(function(v) {
  if (Container.prototype.isPrototypeOf(v)) {
    v.GUID = window.GUID++;
  }
});
```

This however relies on

- ES5. Use the [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)
- You being able to create the array `objs` with all the objects you might want to extend.

Comment: If you add GUID to the prototype of class A, all classes extending from that class A, are getting an unique instance of that class, and therefore have their own, unique GUID.

Comment: @DanielGruszcyk did you read my answer ;) Everyone shares the single property named `GUID` that lives on the `Container.prototype`

Comment: I know that initially all classes extending the parent will see the same value, but if you change the value of the GUID in an instance of a child class, the changed value will be visible only there. Mybe I misunderstood the question, but IMO the guy wants to add a property to the base class, so he can use it in child classes. So I assume he will be changing it in child classes...

Comment: @DanielGruszcyk that doesn't work if you don't know what your doing. For example `foo.GUID = 42;` will set a local property `GUID` on object `foo`. Where as `foo.GUID++` will increment property `GUID` on `Container.prototype`. besides if he can change the GUID on the objects why does he even need to touch the Container.

Comment: @DanielGruszcyk adding a method is cheating. Yes that's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you well, here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mMfdj/1/

And here with automatic unique GUID's:

http://jsfiddle.net/mMfdj/5/

Answer (score 0):

As already described, if GUID is a function you can simply add it to the container prototype. If not, adding this function

```
container.prototype.GUID = function (v) {
  if (arguments.length) // setting the value
    return this.GUID = v;

  return this.hasOwnProperty ('GUID') ? this.GUID : undefined; 
}
```

Will allow you to access a GUID property by using `obj.GUID ()` or set it using `obj.GUID (val)`