# Javascript: Once a 'class/object' has been 'extended', is it possible to re-extend it using a different base 'class/object'?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype-programming

I am trying to add a new property to a tree of classes in an existing JS framework (Wireit). See here for more details: [Javascript: Is it possible to inject new functions into a base 'class/object' that will be available in all sub-'classes/objects'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777201/javascript-is-it-possible-to-inject-new-functions-into-a-base-class-that-will-be)

My initial approach was to redefine the base class but this is proving to be tricky.

I am now wondering if I can sub-class the base class, add my extension and then re-subclass the class which extended the base class to use my base class. Complicated? I'll do a simple diagram to show what I mean....

#### Current inheritance

```
Container --> ImageContainer
Container --> FormContainer
```

#### New inheritance

```
Container --> MyContainer --> ImageContainer
Container --> MyContainer --> FormContainer
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how your diagrams should be interpreted. How does `Container` relate to `ImageContainer` and `FormContainer`, given the fact that there is no "multiple inheritance" in JS?

Comment: @Tomalak - see my edit. Hope it's clearer now. ImageContainer and FormContainer both extend Container.

Comment: How do you intend to alter objects that already exist? You face the same problems.

Comment: @paul: Ah. I see now, I was interpreting the arrows wrongly.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have classes.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - I know. What is the official term in this case? Should I write "base 'class'" or something like that as the other 'Tomalak' did when he refered to 'multiple inheritance'?

Comment: @paul the terms are objects and prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `guid` as a method and be done with it.

```
Container.prototype.GUID = function() {
  return GUIDSystem.getGUID(this);
}
```

Write your own GUIDSystem to return a unique GUID for each object.

**Hint:** Use [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), WeakMap shim and a lazy population of the GUIDs in the map.